# Freestyle outline has gaps

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, freestyle, outliner

When I render with the freestyle feature in cycles, some edges are not outlined. This image was rendered with the default freestyle settings other than the line style, which was changed from stroke to color.[image] How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to elaborate on what you're trying to achieve and what you're getting so far. Illustrate it with some print screens of your settings and renders and/or upload your .blend file. In current form, your question is too broad. Your problem can stem from multiple different things.

Comment: Okay, I´ve updated the post

Answer (score 2):

You have to construct a Line Set by including/excluding [characteristics](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fi/dev/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html#selection-by) of the object in the view.. the default is not serving your purpose, here. If necessary, you can explicitly select edges to be stroked by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> : Edge Menu > *Edge Data* > *Mark Freestyle Edge*.

Here, I've just increased the Crease Angle ( a threshold value ) in the Freestyle settings....

[image]

but there are no end of options. I'd recommend playing with them using the Blender Internal renderer, so you get immediate feedback in the viewport. The settings will still be available when you switch back to Cycles.